# Webpack 2 css-loader substitutes z-index property in production build

Tags: webpack, less, z-index

I am facing strange issue with production build version of our app. We are using React bundled with webpack. Styles are written in less and packed to separate bundle.css with **extract-text-plugin**. I am having `z-index` property all over my app. Problem is, that in production mode, bundle outputs styles with substitute values of z-index property. For instance, `z-index: 9999` will be transpiled to `z-index: 27`. Even if I put `!important` it results into `z-index: 27!important`. I assume that it is done deliberately, but in case if some z-index property set with jss, for example "zIndex: 99", my main 9999 (that was configured with less) will be overlaped by jss inline styles that are remaining the same after build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your production, add `safe` compression:

```
new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
  cssProcessorOptions: {
    safe: true
  }
})
```